# Bootstrap + Masonry add blank divs when grid have empty spaces at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using masonry + bootstrap and notice that when I have a 3-column grid then I have 10 items, it would display a 3x4 grid having 2 blank spaces at the bottom. How could I automatically add 2 empty divs at the bottom just to fill it up and not having those blank spaces? So the total div would become 12 wherein the 2 divs are just blank?

This isn't supposed to be fixed to a 3-column but should dynamically add empty divs whenever it detected that there are N number of empty divs that could be filled up. Should be applicable on load and on resize.

There will be no problem with the `.item` size since they will all have the same width and height (box/square type)

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3bLt5ta/6/) that could now add fillers on the empty spaces on the last row. This is working on the on resize as well by using the `layoutComplete` event. But the problem is, whenever I resize, it keeps on appending new fillers.

Try re-sizing to different sizes and you'll notice it keeps on adding fillers.

In case, here's the code as well.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="hfTotalGridItems" id="hfTotalGridItems" value="10" />
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;        
}
.filler {
    background-color: #999;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
    function calculateRows() {
        var lisInRow = 0;
        var $item = $('.grid .item');
        var $grid = $('.grid');
        var itemWidth = $('.grid .item').width();
        var itemHeight = $('.grid .item').height();

        $item.each(function () {
            if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
                if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
                lisInRow++;
            } else {
                lisInRow++;
            }
        });

        var lisInLastRow = $item.length % lisInRow;
        if (lisInLastRow == 0) lisInLastRow = lisInRow;

        $('.result').html('No: of lis in a row = ' + lisInRow + '<br>' + 'No: of lis in last row = ' + lisInLastRow);

        if (lisInLastRow < lisInRow) {
            var $clonedItem = $('.grid .item:last-child').clone().empty().css({
                width: itemWidth,
                height: itemHeight
            }).addClass('filler');
            $grid.append($clonedItem).masonry('appended', $clonedItem);

        } else {
            if (newTotal > $('#hfTotalGridItems').val()) {
                $grid.masonry('remove', $('.grid .item.filler'));
                $grid.masonry();
            }
        }
    }

    var $grid = $('.grid');

    $grid.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: true,
        gutter: 20
    });

    $grid.masonry('on', 'layoutComplete', function (event) {
        calculateRows(event.length);
    });

    $grid.masonry();
});
```

Comment: **Updated** code wherein it could now count number of columns in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you need to check

1. If the number of original boxes is evenly divisible by the number of boxes in the first row `(originalBoxs % lisInRow === 0)`.
2. If the number of boxes is greater then a max allowed number of boxes. You can calculate the max allowed boxes as below

   ```
   var totalAllowed = lisInRow;
   while (totalAllowed < originalBoxs) {
      totalAllowed += lisInRow;
   }
   ```

If this is true, then you should remove all of the excess boxes. Otherwise add in the filler boxes. Here is a updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8f6u2vd/3/)

I added the updated jQuery code below

```
$(function () {

    // remember the original box lenth. 
    var $item = $('.grid .item');
    var originalBoxs = $item.length;

    function calculateRows() {

        var lisInRow = 0;
        var $item = $('.grid .item');
        var $grid = $('.grid');
        var itemWidth = $('.grid .item').width();
        var itemHeight = $('.grid .item').height();

        // calculate how many boxes are in the first row. 
        $item.each(function () {
            if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
                if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
                lisInRow++;
            } else {
                lisInRow++;
            }
        });

        // calculate how many boxes are in the last row. 
        var lisInLastRow = $item.length % lisInRow;

        $('.result').html('No: of lis in a row = ' + lisInRow + '<br>' + 'No: of lis in last row = ' + lisInLastRow);

        // the total allowed boxes on the page. 
        var totalAllowed = lisInRow;
        while (totalAllowed < originalBoxs) {
            totalAllowed += lisInRow;
        }

        if (($item.length > originalBoxs && originalBoxs % lisInRow === 0) || ($item.length > totalAllowed)) {
            // if the number of original boxes evenly divides into the number of boxes in a row.
            // or the number of boxes on the page is past the max allowed. 
            // remove any filler boxes. 
            var boxesToDelete = $('.grid .item.filler');
            var deleteBoxes = $item.length - totalAllowed;
            for (var i = 0; i < deleteBoxes; i++) {
                // delete unnesecary boxes. 
                $grid.masonry('remove', boxesToDelete[boxesToDelete.length - i - 1]);
            }
        } else if (lisInLastRow !== 0) {
            // if the last row does not equal 0 and the number of boxes is less then the original + the first row
            // then fill it in with new boxes. 
            var $clonedItem = $('.grid .item:last-child').clone().empty().css({
                width: itemWidth,
                height: itemHeight
            }).addClass('filler');
            $grid.append($clonedItem).masonry('appended', $clonedItem);    
        }

    }

    var $grid = $('.grid');

    $grid.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: true,
        gutter: 20
    });

    $grid.masonry('on', 'layoutComplete', function (event) {
        calculateRows(event.length);
    });

    $grid.masonry();
});
```

Comment: It is still not working though... Here's the step to recreate: 1) resize to 5 column grid. 2) resize to 8 column grid, notice fillers being added 3) resize to 7 column grid, notice fillers being added at the bottom. 4) resize to 6 column grid, notice more fillers being added at the bottom 5) resize to 5 column grid, all fillers are removed.

Comment: @user1781041 got it. So what we need to do is calculate a max number of boxes allowed and make sure the filler boxes are not pushing the total number of boxes pass this max number. I will update the answer above.

Comment: This is perfectly working ! Thanks @jjbskir! This is using the exact masonry functionality for appending.  I still need more hours for the bounty award :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bit different version. Please check this traditional [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xagurndd/) for tests.

In short, I have taken the way of non-intrusive modification for Masonry to achieve the expected behavior in the most optimal way.

```js
$(function() {

  var fillerHtml = '<div></div>',
    fillerClassName = 'filler',
    initialItemCount = null;

  function toggleFillers() {
    var masonry = $grid.data('masonry'),
      currentItemCount = masonry.items.length,
      items = masonry.items,
      cols = masonry.cols,
      expectedItemCount = 0,
      lastRowItemCount = 0,
      lastRowFillerCount = 0,
      fillersToRemove = [],
      fillersToAddCount = 0,
      fillersToAdd = [];

    if (initialItemCount === null) {
      initialItemCount = currentItemCount;
    }

    lastRowItemCount = initialItemCount % cols;
    lastRowFillerCount = (lastRowItemCount !== 0) ? cols - lastRowItemCount : 0;
    expectedItemCount = initialItemCount + lastRowFillerCount;
    
    $('.result').html('No: of lis in a row = ' + cols + '<br>' + 'No: of lis in last row = ' + lastRowItemCount);

    if (expectedItemCount !== currentItemCount) {
      if (currentItemCount > expectedItemCount) {
        var itemsToRemove = items.slice(initialItemCount + lastRowFillerCount);

        $.each(itemsToRemove, function(index, item) {
          fillersToRemove.push(item.element);
        });

        masonry.remove(fillersToRemove);
        masonry.layout();
      } else {
        fillersToAddCount = expectedItemCount - currentItemCount;
        fillerClassName = masonry.options.itemSelector.replace('.', '') + ' ' + fillerClassName;

        while (fillersToAddCount) {
          $el = $(fillerHtml).addClass(fillerClassName);
          $grid.append($el);
          fillersToAddCount = fillersToAddCount - 1;
        }

        masonry.reloadItems();
        masonry.layout();
      }
    }
  }

  var $grid = $('.grid');

  $grid.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    isFitWidth: true,
    gutter: 20
  });
  $grid.masonry('on', 'layoutComplete', toggleFillers);
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

```css
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item,
.filler {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
.filler {
  background-color: #999;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="hfTotalGridItems" id="hfTotalGridItems" value="10" />

<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

I've been playing around with Masonry for a while, so I have decided to package this as a plugin, if you will need toy use it elsewhere.

You can install it with bower or simply grab the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/halfzebra/jquery-masonry-autofill/blob/master/src/jquery-masonry-autofill.js)

```
bower install jquery-masonry-autofill
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gzrg8wf/) for a demo with plugin.

Comment: This is perfectly working even though there was a different approach with regards to masonry! Thanks @halfzebra! I like how you created a github on this and created a plugin for everyone to use. This will be very useful to others who wants the same functionality as well. Kudos! @jjbskir was able to pull if off by still using the append functionality of masonry

Comment: @user1781041 thanks for inspiration! I have updated the [repo](https://github.com/halfzebra/jquery-masonry-autofill) with a link to the original question.